# Elementary electromagnetism problem - Electric field generated by points that form an equilateral triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am a newbie at physics and i just started learning electromagnetism at the university. Some help would be very welcome on the following questions (my question and/or result and/or partial work will be given in parenthesis and will be in **bold**). The follwing problem is part of a previous exam.

We place ourselves in the usual cartesian xyz coordinate system with origin $O$. On the plane $xOy$ we put an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with side length $3$ such that $O$ is its center. We place one charge of value $q$ at each endpoint of the triangle.

1) What is the length of $\vec{OA}$? (Obviously $\sqrt{3}$). What is the electric field at the point O? **(Isn't it $0$ because $ \vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+ \vec{OC}=\vec0$?)**

2) Let $M=(0,0,z_m)$ be a point on the line $Oz$. What is the "sense" and the direction of the electric field at the point $M$ if $z_m>0$? If $z_m<0$? **This should be $\vec{E}(M)= \vec{e_z}\frac{3qz_m}{4 \pi \epsilon_0||\vec{AM}||^3}$ if my calculations are correct. I considered the pyramid symmetric to the pyramid $ABCM$ by $M$ and noted that $\vec{AM}+\vec{BM} + \vec{CM}=3\vec{OM}$.** Sketch the graph of the curve $\vec{E}(z_m)$ **(how do i do this?)**.

3) A small test charge $q$ is placed at $O$. **How do i justify that it is a balanced (or is it equilibrium?) point** (in French it is point d'équilibre)?. **In which case is this point stable (or unstable) by the movement along the axis $Oz$**?

4) Calculate the electric potential $V(M)$. **Here i get $V(M)= \frac{3q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 || \vec{AM}||}$**.  Specify the chosen convention as to where the electric potential is zero **(What does this mean?)**. What relationship can we deduce for $\vec{E}(M)$ and $V(M)$? **Do i just need to express $\vec{AM}$ in terms of $z$ by the Pythagoras' theorem and then confirm the equation $\vec{ \nabla} (V) = - \vec{E}$ or is there more to it?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Length of $\vec {OA}$ why not $3/\sqrt {2}$?

Comment: The field at the point $O$ is zero because of the symmetry of the forces.

Comment: Usually you should only ask one question per post. Also, at the moment this question does not appear to be on topic, based on the site's homework policy.

Comment: @Sofia The radius of the circumscribed circle is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}a$. Now setting $a=3$ gives the result. 

Also regarding the symmetry, by which condition are they symmetric (what is the axis or point of symmetry)?

Comment: @Sean Should i delete the homework tag? :( The problem also builds up on the previous questions and that is why i left it there as a whole.

Comment: No the tag should definitely be there. To me, the biggest issue is that this doesn't boil down to a single _conceptual_ question.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski   let's hurry, your question is indeed home-work, s.t. the time is short. For the graph $\vec E(M)$ you take points $z$ both <0 and >0, as dense as you can, calculate $\vec E$ for ach one, and draw a graph with z along the coordinate $x$ and $E$ along coord. $y$.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski the graph will tell you where the force on the charge is zero. As to the zero potential, take it where you want, preferable in $O$.

Comment: @Sofia Thank you! But what does it mean for the point to be stable by the movement?

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski Did you erase some words from the text? The text is not entire, all the edited parts disappeared. Anyway, please see: the intensity of a field is tested with a positive, unit charge. Assume also that all the charges in the triangle corner are negative. Above the triangle, the test-particle is attracted downwards, right? Below the triangle the test-particle is attracted upwards, right? Then, what is the field at $O$? And if the test-charge moves only due to the field, what happens in the point $O$? But, please, check your text, I don't know why don't I see the edited parts.

Comment: @Sofia I have not deleted anything, maybe the latex codes do not show properly. Try refreshing the page, maybe that can help. Also the only point of equilibrium should be $O$. But how do i check if the equilibrium is stable or not (by the given movement)?